# Are Almanac page paths predetermined?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

So far, I have had absolutely *zero* luck catching a single Almanac Page in *Assassin's Creed 3*. Every time I start to chase one, I am immediately met with a pop-up stating:

> "The Almanac page is lost. Come back later and try again."

... or something to that effect, anyway. I just can't seem to catch the pesky things!

**Is there a predetermined path that I can learn for these pages, or are they randomly generated?** I've tried watching a few, but with them disappearing so quickly, it is very difficult for me to tell.

Comment: The best way is to get above them, and jump into their path, once you catch one or two you can easily guess where it will go.

Comment: In my experience you have at least 30 seconds or so with all of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The path of an almanac page is predetermined, so you can learn where it will go, beat it there and then just wait.

They tend to follow obvious free running paths anyway, so they're generally not *too* hard to catch unless they go over things like rooftops and the like where you don't have a path to follow.

Comment: I think they might have multiple paths each so they always head away from you as you first approach (so you can't just see which direction they go once and then just approach it from that point the next time).

Answer (score 5):

I've found that an easy way to get them is to get on top of an adjacent building, rather than climbing the building that they're on the top of, as they'll start to move while you're still climbing. If you're already on top of the structure, it'll start to move and you'll already be able to free run, and can catch them no problemo.

Comment: Yup - this is the easiest way to catch them without camping out to track their movements (and then having them disappear so you have to run around until they come back again).